# Implicit conversion from data type varchar to varbinary(max) is not allowed c#

Tags: c#, sql-server

I am trying to insert byte[] into varbinary(MAX) column in sql server 
Below is my code

```
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("Insert Into Details values ('@name','@Biometric','@TemplateBytesLength','@date') ", con);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("name", txt_name.Text.Trim());
SqlParameter sqlParam = cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Biometric", bTemplateDataOne);
sqlParam.DbType = DbType.Binary;
//cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("Biometric", bTemplateDataOne);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("TemplateBytesLength", bTemplateDataOne.Length);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("date", DateTime.Now);

cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
con.Close();
```

bTemplateDataOne is an byte[]

```
byte[] bTemplateDataOne;
```

The error i am getting is this 

Implicit conversion from data type varchar to varbinary(max) is not allowed. Use the CONVERT function to run this query. 

Why it does not allow to insert data into SQL table
[image]

Comment: show table schema

Comment: You've put your parameter names inside `'` quote marks - meaning that you're trying to insert the literal *strings* such as `'@name'` rather than whatever has been provided as the `@name` parameter.

Comment: is this "bTemplateDataOne" a byte? seen it

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever , naah man its not a problem , adding @ in parameter still show that same error

Comment: @reds yes , bTemplateDataOne is a byte[ ]

Comment: No, you've misunderstood what I'm saying. I'm saying that in the *values* clause of your insert statement, you're trying to insert four *strings* that happen to contain the names of some parameters.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever , ohh let me check

Comment: You should get rid of all the `'` in the insert statement, not just for the Biometric column.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever , Thanks man it works

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that better solution will be using SqlParameter like this:

```
cmd.Parameters.Add("@Biometric", SqlDbType.VarBinary, 8000).Value = bTemplateDataOne;
```

Comment: Huh? You want to save space in the database by multiplying the amount of data to be stored by 4/3 and storing as a string rather than using a built-in type that is *designed* for storing arbitrary byte data?

Comment: This seem to have nothing to do with the question. And wont save any space as suggested.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever, you right. Unfortunatelly I can't delete this answer :/ I've edited it and I propose different approach. I hope it is better.